# Double FOR loop to move files

Tags: batch-file

Thanks for any help in advance.

I am trying to make a batch file to move files in some folder.

Just a bit background.
I have a folder and the structure as below:

c:\test

- app1\app1.exe
- app2\app2.exe
- app3\app3.doc
- xx[xx].exe
- xx2\xx2.exe
- xx3\xx3.EXE

In other words, I have a folder that contains a few sub folders, each of the sub-dir has some files. What I want to do is using a script, loop all the folders, move all files contain "app" to folder app, then move all files have "xx" to folder xx - in order to minimize the effort, I've already created these two folders so the script doesn't need to decide if it has to make a new dir.

Below is my script,

```
@echo off
rem loop xx
FOR /r "C:\test\" %%G in (*xx*.*) DO (
Echo Found file - %%G
copy %%G c:\testf\xx\
set pathname=%%G
for %%K in ("%pathname%") do ( set filepath=%%~dpK
set filename=%%~nxK
echo Filepath is %filepath%
echo %filename% >> c:\output.log )
echo full is %pathname% )
rem loop app
FOR /r "C:\test\" %%H in (*app*.*) DO (
Echo Found file - %%H
copy %%H c:\testf\app\
set pathname=%%H
for %%L in ("%pathname%") do ( set filepath=%%~dpL
set filename=%%~nxL
echo Filepath is %filepath%
echo %filename% >> c:\output.log )
echo full is %pathname% )
Echo "All Done"
```

The current output log shows

```
xx3.EXE  
xx3.EXE  
xx3.EXE  
app3.EXE  
app3.EXE  
app3.EXE
```

and xx files were sent to xx folder only but app files didnt.
Could I have any help to deal with this problem?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the path of your app files includes spaces - that would break the COPY command unless you include quotes.

Your script is much more complicated than need be. There isn't any need for the inner loop. You can also eliminate code by using a loop to get your two strings. I would have written it like so to get the same result, with the COPY command fixed with quotes:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (xx app) do (
  for /r "c:\test\" %%F in (*%%A*.*) do (
    echo Found file - %%F
    copy "%%F" "c:\testf\%%A\"
    echo Filepath is %%~dpF
    echo %%~nxF >>c:\output.log
    echo full is %%F
  )
)
echo "All Done"
```

Please note that copying the same file name from multiple source directories into one target directory will result in only one file - last one copied wins.

Comment: Hi Dbenham, thanks for the help. I just tried again your script however I am still getting the "The System cannot find the path specified" after looping xx files - all xx files are correctly sent to xx folder but app files dont seem to be. Thanks again. ps, output is showing correctly, [xx].EXE 
xx2.exe 
xx3.EXE 
app1.EXE 
app2.exe 
app3.EXE

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND` to test your files :

```
@echo off&cls

for %%a in (xx app) do call:Treat %%a

exit /b
:Treat
echo Treating : [%1]
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/a-d/b/s ^| find "%1"') do echo copy "%%a" "c:\test\%1"
```

I put an echo before the copy that you can test the output.